# How to show horizontal grid lines without the Y-Axis in Flot?

Tags: javascript, flot

I've been searching the [flot docs](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-axes) and examples for a way to show the horizontal (y-axis) grid lines without plotting the vertical axis values (e.g. 0 to 100) without any success.

Is there a way to do this without the y-axis values?

[image]

and not this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using `tickFormatter`:

```
yaxis: {
  tickFormatter: function(){return ''}
}
```

See https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-axes.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3es51qqx/)